# Extract correct number of characters from cell

Tags: excel, find, vba

I would like to extract the correct number of characters from a cell in Excel.

The following possibilities can be found in the cells:

- AAI CA 05/19/18 C30
- AAI CA 05/19/18 C32
- AAIO CA 05/19/18 C35
- AAI CA 05/19/18 C300
- AAIO CA 05/19/18 C300

I want to retrieve the date and the C + x-numbers (in this case 2 and 3 numbers) on the right.

For the x-numbers on the right I have the following formula

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" C",A1),5)
```

However, how do I make sure that the right "C" (the second one) is used in my formula?

In addition, I am struggling with retrieve the data from the cell. The date is always 8 characters long.

Comment: Classic for `RegEx` , nice demo site : https://regex101.com/r/sUOCSd/3

Comment: Do you want an Excel formula or a VBA function? With VBA, I would suggest to use the split-command

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is in A2, then try this...

```
=MID(A2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","^",2))+1,255)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Find, Mid and Trim.

Try this:-

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("C",A1,FIND("C",A1))+FIND("C",A1)-2,LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: edited the formula to include date in the result which I missed earlier

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("CA ",A1)+3,8)
```

and copy down.  In **C1** enter:

```
=MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),4*999-998,999)),2,9999)
```

and copy down.

[image]

This gets the date as a string and the digits following that final **C**.